# Sharing Facebook links on Twitter: why no link preview or snippet generated?

Tags: facebook, twitter, links, sharing, tweet

I want to share a Facebook page, or in fact **any** Facebook URL, on
Twitter. (I.e., I want to "Tweet a link to a Facebook page, etc.")

- Why is no "link preview" generated?
- Why is no "snippet" generated?

Is it

- [My fault?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128604/facebook-urls-shared-on-twitter-no-link-preview-is-generated-and-the-user-must)
- [Twitter's fault?](https://twittercommunity.com/t/facebook-cards-no-open-graph-tags-even/135910)
- Facebook's fault?

The other way around, sharing a Twitter link on Facebook, works properly
of course.

No I don't want to link my Twitter and Facebook accounts and then share the link on Facebook and have it automatically post on Twitter. All I want to do is occasionally press the Tweet button and toss in a Facebook URL and tweet it and have a proper link preview and snippet generated by Twitter.